# how to avoid overlapping edge and node when using graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

As title,I want to draw an image of ELF file format.The ELF Header has offset of program headers table and section headers table,so I want to use two arrows pointer to point out the relationship.But the edges overlap the node(record) even after I have overlap=false and splines=true set.I have search for a while,but my situation is that the arrows somewhat point to parts of itself.

Following is the dot file I am using to generate the png file.

```
digraph g {
//margin="1"
overlap='scale'
graph [rankdir="LR"]

"ELF File" [
label="<f0> ELF Header\n e_shoff=0x118| <f1> Program Headers Table | <f2> .text | <f3> .data | <f4> .rodata| <f5> .comment | <f6> .shstrtab | <f8> .symtab | <f9> .rel.text | <f7> Section Table"
shape="record"
];

"ELF File":f0 -> "ELF File":f1 [label="e_phoffset"]
"ELF File":f0 -> "ELF File":f7 [label="e_shoff"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use "east" node ports on one of the edges, so that this edge appears on opposite side of the record.  You do this by appending `:e` to the node name.  For example:

```
"ELF File":f0:e -> "ELF File":f7:e [label="e_shoff"]
```